# Caching in python using *args and lambda functions

Tags: python, caching, lambda

I recently attempted Googles  [foo.bar challenge](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/google-foobar-how-searching-web-earned-software-graduate-job-google-1517284). After my time was up I decided to try find a solution to the problem I couldn't do and found a solution [here](https://github.com/rtheunissen/foobar/blob/master/line_up_the_captives.py)  (includes the problem statement if you're interested). I'd previously been making a dictionary for every function I wanted to cache but it looks like in this solution any function/input can be cached using the same syntax.

Firstly I'm confused on how the code is even working, the *args variable isn't inputted as an argument (and prints to nothing). Heres an modified minimal example to illustrate my confusion:

```
mem = {}

def memoize(key, func, *args):
    """
    Helper to memoize the output of a function
    """

    print(args)

    if key not in mem:
        # store the output of the function in memory
        mem[key] = func(*args)

    return mem[key]

def example(n):
    return memoize(
        n,
        lambda: longrun(n),
    )

def example2(n):
     return memoize(
        n,
        longrun(n),
     )

def longrun(n):
    for i in range(10000):
        for j in range(100000):
            2**10
    return n
```

Here I use the same **memoize** function but with a print. The function **example** returns **memoize(n, a lambda function,)**. The function **longrun** is just an identity function with lots of useless computation so it's easy to see if the cache is working (**example(2)** will take ~5 seconds the first time and be almost instant after).

Here are my confusions:

- Why is the third argument of memoize empty? When args is printed in **memoize** it prints (). Yet somehow mem[key] stores func(*args) as func(key)?
- Why does this behavior only work when using the lambda function (**example** will cache but **example2** won't)? I thought lambda: longrun(n) is just a short way of giving as input a function which returns longrun(n).

As a bonus, does anyone know how you could memoize functions using a decorator?

Also I couldn't think of a more descriptive title, edits welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache

Comment: Please see the docs and use search. The [`*args` notation provides variadic arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists). As you don't provide any arguments, `*args` is empty. `example2` doesn't work, since you don't provide it a *function*, you provide the *result of calling a function*. It should read `memoize(n, longrun, n)`.

Comment: Thanks @janbrohl, exactly what I was after regarding the decorator!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation [`*args`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) stands for a variable number of positional arguments. For example, `print` can be used as `print(1)`, `print(1, 2)`, `print(1, 2, 3)` and so on. Similarly, `**kwargs` stands for a variable number of keyword arguments.

Note that the names `args` and `kwargs` are just a convention - it's the `*` and `**` symbols that make them variadic.

Anyways, `memoize` uses this to accept basically *any* input to *func*. If the result of *func* isn't cached, it's called with the arguments. In a function call, `*args` is basically the reverse of `*args` in a function definition. For example, the following are equivalent:

```
# provide *args explicitly
print(1, 2, 3)
# unpack iterable to *args
arguments = 1, 2, 3
print(*arguments)
```

If `args` is empty, then calling `print(*args)` is the same as calling `print()` - no arguments are passed to it.

---

Functions and lambda functions are *the same* in python. It's simply a different notation for creating a function object.

The problem is that in `example2`, you are not passing a function. You *call* a function, then pass on its result. Instead, you have to pass on the function and its argument separately.

```
def example2(n):
    return memoize(
        n,
        longrun,  # no () means no call, just the function object
        # all following parameters are put into *args
        n
    )
```

---

Now, some implementation details: why is `args` empty and why is there a separate key?

- The empty `args` comes from your definition of the lambda. Let's write that as a function for clarity:

  ```
  def example3(n):
      def nonlambda():
          return longrun(n)
      return memoize(n, nonlambda)
  ```

  Note how `nonlambda` takes *no arguments*. The parameter `n` is bound from the containing scope as a closure, [bound from the containing scope](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions). As such, you don't have to pass it to memoize - it is already bound inside the `nonlambda`. Thus, `args` is empty in memoize, even though `longrun` does receive a parameter, because the two don't interact directly.
- Now, why is it `mem[key] = f(*args)`, not `mem[key] = f(key)`? That's actually slightly the wrong question; the right question is "why isn't it `mem[f, args] = f(*args)`?".

  Memoization works because the same input to the same function leads to the same output. That is, `f, args` *identifies* your output. Ideally, your `key` would be `f, args` as that's the only relevant information.

  The problem is you need a way to look up `f` and `args` inside `mem`. If you ever tried putting a `list` inside a `dict`, you know there are some types which don't work in mappings (or any other suitable lookup structure, for that matter). So if you define `key = f, args`, you cannot memoize functions taking mutable/unhashable types. Python's `functools.lru_cache` actually has this limitation.

  Defining an explicit `key` is one way of solving this problem. It has the advantage that the caller can select an appropriate key, for example taking `n` without any modifications. This offers the best optimization potential. However, it breaks easily - using just `n` misses out the actual function called. Memoizing a second function with the same input would break your cache.

  There are alternative approaches, each with pros and cons. Common is the explicit conversion of types: `list` to `tuple`, `set` to `frozenset`, and so on. This is slow, but the most precise. Another approach is to just call `str` or `repr` as in `key = repr((f, args, sorted(kwargs.items())))`, but it relies on every value having a proper `repr`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand what *args means, my confusion comes from the fact that when example is called it's given *args as empty. The dictionary should be storing mem[key] = f(key) but instead it looks like its storing mem[key] = f() (which shouldn't even work with longrun). I would have expected to have seen

def example(n):
    return memoize(
        n,
        lambda: longrun(n),
        n
    ) (like how you have demonstrated example2, which works without the last argument too. This is my question, how does this still work without the last argument?)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem in example2, I missed that!

Comment: @HBeel I've added an explanation for `f()` and `key`. In short, `example` does not pass on `longrun` (which needs a parameter) but the `lambda` function (which does not need a parameter).

Comment: Thanks for the additional information @MisterMiyagi. If I understand correctly `example` is combining a function and its arguments into a single function (which takes no arguments); something like f_n() = f(n)? Your second point also makes a lot of sense, thanks. For this particular problem, why did the author of this code even both with `*args` if it's always passed empty? Perhaps a general piece of code they use often, sometimes using extra arguments?